# Select constant and union with another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Category table with pk and `sName` columns. I want to add additional row with constant values such as
`pk = -1, sName = "NONE"`
so that the user can select `"NONE"` row if they want to.

Below is the code to retrieve Categories,

```
var catList = from c in context.Category
              where c.iStatus == 1 && c.iCat1ID == Cat1ID
              select new { c.pk, c.sName };
```

Below is the code to retrieve constant row,

```
var noneList = from c in context.Category
               select new { pk = -1, sName = "  NONE" };
```

Then I add `noneList` to the `catList` by

```
catList = catList.Union(noneList);
```

This works fine when there is at least 1 row in Category table. When there are 0 rows in Category table, `noneList` will not get anything from the query and `catList` will not have the `"NONE"` row.

I have searched a lot how to union with a row with constants but I was not able to find an example that satisfies my situation.

Here's another attempt.

```
var catList = from c in context.Category
              where c.iStatus == 1 && c.iCat1ID == Cat1ID
              select new { c.pk, c.sName };

var noneList = new[] { new { pk = -1, sName = " NONE" }};

catList = catList.Union(noneList);
```

This code does not give any errors at design time but when I run it, it throws:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

[Edit]
By converting catList to an array looks like it does not throw any exception.

```
var aa = CatList.ToArray().Union(NoneList);
```

Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it Entity Framework? Materialize the query first to perform union in memory. By calling `castList.ToArray().Union()` (or `ToList()`).

Comment: Note that while `AsEnumerable()` may work here, it doesn't do so by materializing the query. It effectively just casts the object to `IEnumerable<T>` so that the right provider is used for queries. As such, it's definitely preferable to using e.g. `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to do it this way, but I just created another variable and converted catList to an array and did union with noneList. I do not like the way I did it but it looks like it's the only option I have unless I can implement union with constant row in one linq query.

Comment: Also I found out that I need to have a list as a final result since I am binding it to a dropdown combobox so I do aa.List() at the end. How much performance will it have when I have many records in the table and I do .ToArray() and .ToList()? And yes it is Entity Framework!

Comment: The 'problem' here is to make EF to generate appropriate SQL. Can you write the query you'd like in pure SQL? I'm noot sure. So EF can't as well. So you read and load the data first in memory, then union how you want. LINQ to Objects is way more flexible than LINQ to Entities.

Comment: You can chain calls so no additional variables are needed, it's pretty straightforward, readable and usual thing (when you want something EF can't do, can't generate SQL for)

Comment: Final call should look like this: `data.ToArray().Union(memory).ToArray()`. First materializes data from db, second materializes union in memory. Two calls are very different in nature and underlying structure but still are both dereffered.

Comment: Is the last call of ToArray() necesarry from data.ToArray().Union(memory).ToArray()? I'm not clearly understanding the purpose of it. Could you elaborate more why? thank you!

Comment: It's necessary and it's not, it depends. Union() returns IEnumerable, i.e. not-yet-materialized deferred query, like any other LINQ query. Every time you iterate it will perform union again, so you need either do it once or materializes it. See how LINQ works in general.